# Upgrade Manager upgraded to 14.04.3 which is a Daily Build

Tags: 14.04, daily-build

I upgraded our Dell server from 12.04.5 to 14.04.3, this later release is a Daily Build. Is there a convenient way to downgrade to 14.04.2? How stable is 14.04.3? Also why would upgrade manager recommend upgrading to a Daily Build? Upgrade happened on Aug-5, 2015 2pm PDT (GMT-7), yet release date for 14.04.3 is Aug-6. Is it because of the time zone differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

14.04.3 is not a daily build.

At present an up to date Ubuntu 14.04 shows

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
```

it has been released today.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseSchedule

14.04.3 is a stable release, there is no need to downgrade anything.

And also 14.04.3 is actually not a completely separate release. It accumulates all updates from 14.04.2. So some packages, like `lsb` could come prior to the release date.